# Retrieve a message from Node.js api using Vue.js

Tags: node.js, api, vue.js, axios

i'm working on login system using Vue.js (frontend) and Node.js api (backend) and using Axios to connect between them.
i know well how to send error messages from Node.js api to Vue.js application as follow

```
async register(){
      try
      {
     await AthenticationService.register({
          email: this.email,
          password: this.password,
          firstName:this.firstName,
          lastName:this.lastName,
          gender: this.gender,
          birthYear: this.birthYearSelected,
          language: this.languageSelected
        })
      }catch (error) {
        this.error = error.response.data.error
      }    
    }
```

But i don't know, if i want to send a message like "registration is done activate now" how can i do that?

Comment: put that inside the `try` statement after the `await AthenticationService.register()` call

Comment: you want to know how to send a message using axios?

Comment: yes i want to know how to send a message using axios -boussadjra brahim